# Make a 3-cycle with conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

As a part of proof that $A_n$, $n >= 5$ has no normal subgroups. I need to prove that it's not possible to make a cycle with conjugation:

Let permutation $\pi = (1 2)(3 4)$.
Is it possible to find such $g$ that $g \pi g^{-1}$ is a 3-cycle? $g \in S_n, n >= 5$
Please provide proof.

Comment: Nope.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $(g\pi g^{-1})^2=\text{id}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why are you answering in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(1\,2)(3\,4)g^{-1}=(g(1)\,g(2))(g(3)\,g(4))$$
and so is a product of two $2$-cycles.

Comment: What about if g is longer than 4 elements?

Comment: I assumed, you meant to write $g^{-1}(3)$ and $g^{-1}(4)$. Is that right?

Comment: @Draex_ No, it is correct the way it is written (assuming you apply permutations in order from right to left). And it doesn't matter what $g$ does to any other elements, as those changes are undone afterwards (that's one of the ideas of conjugation). Try it yourself with a few examples, and see. For instance, with $g = (1234567)$, we have $g\pi g^{-1} = (23)(45)$.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur for explanation. I'm still having trouble proving that this equality is true. Can you please explain how you got it?

Comment: @Draex_ Try to see why $g\pi g^{-1}$ sends $g(1)$ to $g(2)$ (apply the three permutations one by one from the right, starting with $g^{-1}$). Then repeat for $g(2)$ to $g(1)$, and similarly for $g(3)$ and $g(4)$. That's basically all there is to it.

Comment: @Arthur But why am I considering only those 4 inputs? How can I be sure that nothing else is relevant?

Comment: @Draex_ You can't. You should make sure. Take any element _other_ than $g(1),g(2),g(3),g(4)$. Apply $g^{-1}$ and see that you get none of $1,2,3,4$. So $\pi$ doesn't touch it. And then $g$ reverses whatever $g^{-1}$ did.

Answer (score 0):

Conjugation by $g$ may be interpreted as relabelling the elements of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ according to $g$. It just gives the elements that permutations act on new names, but doesn't change any of the "important" properties of the permutations. (More rigorously: Conjugation by a fixed element $g$ is an isomorphism.)

Specifically, no matter what $g$ is, $g\pi g^{-1}$ will always be a product of two disjoint $2$-cycles.

Comment: Can you provide a proof please?

Comment: @Draex_ If you just want the one-line calculation, then Lord Shark's answer will likely be sufficient. Also, haven't you come across a similar result in linear algebra? Conjugating linear transformations by an invertible matrix may be interpreted as a change of basis. This is exactly the same (and may even be seen as a special case).